# Using the Axiom Schema of Separation on a Cartesian Product to carve out arbitrary relations

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

In Kenneth Kunen's "*The Foundations of Mathematics*", the **Axiom Schema of Separation** is stated as follows:

> $$\forall A \Big ( \exists B\  \forall z \big (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in A \land \varphi(z) \big) \Big )$$

Using this axiom, I would like to carve out specific subsets of any **Cartesian Product** of the form $S \times T$ (where $S$ and $T$ can be any arbitrary set).

I want these specific subsets to represent any arbitrary "relation".

Kunen provides the following comment on a *relation* $R$:

> *$R$* is a (binary) relation iff $R$ is a set of ordered pairs $-$that is, $$\forall z \in R \ \exists x,y \ [z=\langle x,y\rangle]$$

Although the author has not explicitly mentioned the relationship between a "predicate/formula" $\varphi$ and a relation $R$, I am assuming that the elements of $R$ correspond to any $x,y$ pair that results in $\varphi(x,y)$ evaluating to "**True**". I will denote this as $\varphi_{_R}$...i.e. the predicate that is used in the construction of $R$. ($\color{red}{\text{If this is a misguided notion, please let me know}}$)

---

Let the $A$ in the Axiom Schema of Separation be $S \times T$.

*Carving out a relation.*

$\exists B \ \forall z \Big (z \in B \leftrightarrow z \in S \times T \land \exists x,y \big (z=\langle x,y \rangle \land \varphi_{_R}(x,y) \big ) \Big )$

In this case, I have let my $\varphi (z)$ be defined as $\exists x,y \big (z=\langle x,y \rangle \land \varphi_{_R}(x,y) \big ) $. This construction of the set $B$ is the relation $R$ (i.e. $B$ = $R$)

Does this look alright? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not very clear... We have defined the cartesian product $S \times T$. To do this, we have **proved** that, for arbitrary $S,T$, their product exists: this prove needs Separation.

Comment: Having done that, how to recover a *relation* $R$ from $S \times T$, **provided** that we have a formula $\varphi$ specifying it ? Using Separation again: $∃R ∀z(z∈R↔ (z ∈ S×T ∧ \varphi(z)))$.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that is effectively what I did, is it not? Do you disagree with the idea of: "let my $\varphi (z)$ be defined as $\exists x,y \big (z=\langle x,y \rangle \land \varphi_{_R}(x,y) \big ) $"